# How to keep a text field empty in Android?

Tags: android

I am new to android development , i am trying to develop an app where user can keep a few text field empty,
However when user doesn't provide any input in the text field app crashes.
How do we handle empty text field in android

Following is my code for text Field.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffb7ffbf"/>`
```

java code:

```
TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
a1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: im guessing you do something with the t1.getText(), and it throw an null pointer exception, an im right?

Comment: This isn't enough code to see why the app is crashing. What else is your Activity doing with the text field?

Comment: @Akariuz i  guess u are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure if the `TextBox` is not empty before parsing the value to the `int` as

```
 if (e.length()>0) {
     int a1= Integer.parseInt(e.getText().toString());
 }
```

Else you can get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: for Invalid int: "";`

Answer (score 3):

you should cast EditText instead of TextView.

```
EditText t1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Comment: @NaiveBz `public class EditText extends TextView` so it shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

String aux = t1.getText.toString();

if(aux.length() > 0)
   a1= Integer.parseInt(aux);
else
// the text is empty
```

getText.toString will bring you something always so it can be and string size 0, wich is empty. that will make the parseInt() throw an error because it won find a number in the string.
So you have to ask if the length of the string > 0, before the parse.